# How to work with React, Email JS and e.target

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm trying to build a form that is implemented with Email JS.

**What I want to do?**

- After click the send button it should be reset. No checks in the checkbox, Price should reset to $0.00.

###### What's happening?

- Checkbox are unchecked but Price won't reset to $0.00 after button clicked.

###### Tools I used

- Tailwind
- emailjs/browser
- Vite

Here's the code that I've been working so far. This is what it will look like.
[image]
When I checked what's in `e.target` I got the Price (marked red) into this so I was assuming that `e.target.reset()` will work in this part too but it won't reset. I don't know why this won't reset when it's in `e.target`

[image]

```
import { useState } from 'react';
// EmailJS
import EmailJS from '@emailjs/browser';

const App = () => {
  // EmailJS
  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    EmailJS.sendForm(
      'YOUR_SERVICE_ID', // Please put your service ID if you have Email JS.
      'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', // Please put your template ID if you have Email JS.
      e.target,
      'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY' // Please put your key if you have Email JS.
    ).then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result.text);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error.text);
      }
    );
    e.target.reset();
  };

  // Checkbox
  const list = [
    {
      name: 'A',
      price: 50,
    },
    {
      name: 'B',
      price: 50,
    },
  ];

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(new Array(list.length).fill(false));
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  const toggle = (place) => {
    const updatedChecked = checked.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === place) {
        return !item;
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });

    setChecked(updatedChecked);

    const initialValue = 0;
    const totalPrice = updatedChecked.reduce((acc, currentTorF, index) => {
      if (currentTorF === true) {
        return acc + list[index].price;
      }
      return acc;
    }, initialValue);

    setTotal(totalPrice);
  };

  const getTotalPrice = (price) => {
    return `$${price.toFixed(2)} `;
  };

  // JSX
  return (
    <>
      <div className='flex mx-36'>
        <div className='flex-1'>
          <form onSubmit={sendEmail} required>
            <fieldset className='border border-solid rounded border-gray-300 p-3'>
              <legend className='p-1'>Choice</legend>

              <ul>
                {list.map(({ name, price }, index) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={index} className='flex justify-between'>
                      <div className='p-1'>
                        <input
                          type='checkbox'
                          checked={checked[index]}
                          onChange={() => toggle(index)}
                          id={`linked-${index}`}
                          name='services'
                          value={name}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor={`linked-${index}`} className='p-1'>
                          {name}
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div>{getTotalPrice(price)}</div>
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset className='flex justify-between p-8'>
              <label htmlFor='total'>Price</label>
              <input
                type='text'
                name='total'
                value={getTotalPrice(total)}
                className='w-16 border-none outline-none'
                readOnly
              />
            </fieldset>

            {/* Send button */}
            <button
              className='table mx-auto border border-gray-300 rounded mt-4 px-6 py-1'
              type='submit'
            >
              Send
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Maybe try `e.target.value`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reset` method won't work because the form is not in control over the values in the inputs, React is.

I would recommend that you change some things up. Move your list into a state and add the `checked` property to each list item object. This will keep your data grouped.

The `total` value is always calculated based on the checked items in the `list`. Since we've now grouped added `checked` property to each object, we can calculate the total by looping over the `list`. Use `useMemo` for the `total`. The reason for this is that you want to calculate `total` after every time that `list` has been updated. With `useMemo` you can store each calculation and reuse the stored total whenever the same `list` state occurs.

```
import { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
// EmailJS
import EmailJS from '@emailjs/browser';

const App = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([
    {
      name: 'A',
      price: 50,
      checked: false
    },
    {
      name: 'B',
      price: 50,
      checked: false
    },
  ]);

  const total = useMemo(() => {
    const initialValue = 0;
    
    return list.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      if (cur.checked === true) {
        acc += cur.price;
      }

      return acc;
    }, initialValue);
  }, [list]);

  const resetForm = () => {
    setList(prevState => 
      prevState.map(listItem => ({
        ...listItem,
        checked: false
      }))
    );
  };

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    EmailJS.sendForm(
      'YOUR_SERVICE_ID', // Please put your service ID if you have Email JS.
      'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', // Please put your template ID if you have Email JS.
      e.target,
      'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY' // Please put your key if you have Email JS.
    ).then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result.text);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error.text);
      }
    );
    
    resetForm();
  };

  const toggle = (toggleIndex) => {
    setList(prevState => 
      prevState.map((listItem, index) => {
        if (toggleIndex !== index) {
          return listItem;
        }

        return ({
          ...listItem,
          checked: !listItem.checked
        });
      })
    );
  };

  const getTotalPrice = (price) => {
    return `$${price.toFixed(2)} `;
  };

  // JSX
  return (
    <>
      <div className='flex mx-36'>
        <div className='flex-1'>
          <form onSubmit={sendEmail} required>
            <fieldset className='border border-solid rounded border-gray-300 p-3'>
              <legend className='p-1'>Choice</legend>

              <ul>
                {list.map(({ name, price, checked }, index) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={index} className='flex justify-between'>
                      <div className='p-1'>
                        <input
                          type='checkbox'
                          checked={checked}
                          onChange={() => toggle(index)}
                          id={`linked-${index}`}
                          name='services'
                          value={name}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor={`linked-${index}`} className='p-1'>
                          {name}
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div>{getTotalPrice(price)}</div>
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset className='flex justify-between p-8'>
              <label htmlFor='total'>Price</label>
              <input
                type='text'
                name='total'
                value={getTotalPrice(total)}
                className='w-16 border-none outline-none'
                readOnly
              />
            </fieldset>

            {/* Send button */}
            <button
              className='table mx-auto border border-gray-300 rounded mt-4 px-6 py-1'
              type='submit'
            >
              Send
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I checked the code and it worked. Thank you so much and I'm gonna go through these codes to understand. I might message you again if there's any question about it.

Comment: What is in the ```prevState```?  Is it same as ```setList```?  Also is there a way to look at the value using by ```console.log```?

Comment: A state update function like `setList` accepts a callback function. This function exposes the current state and enables you to use the state before updating. So basically `prevState` has the same value as `list`. Do you know how to use a `useEffect` hook? It will allow you to log your changed states.

Comment: I'm not understanding the ```checked: toggleIndex === index ? !listItem.checked : listItem.checked``` .  What will it be in ```toggleIndex```? ```index``` will have array numbers like ```[0], [1]. [2]...``` right, and when it's ```true``` checkbox will be unchecked and when it's ```false``` checkbox will be checked.

Comment: `toggleIndex` will be the index of the clicked list item. So it will loop through every list item and checks if the index matches. If it does, then it will return the opposite of `listItem.checked`, otherwise it will just return `listItem.checked` without any alteration. Ternary operators can be hard to read. I've changed the function to a more readable example without the ternary operator.

Comment: I understood. Thank you! One more thing that I can't really understand is if the ```reset()``` won't work because the form is not in control over the values in the inputs, React is in control then how did the checkboxes worked with ```reset()```  after submitting the button? I think I'm missing something here.

Comment: That's because you're always still able to manipulate input elements through DOM manipulation. You can try it out in your React application by changing any element in the DOM through the inspector tools. But whenever your component rerenders because of a state update, then all those DOM manipulations will be gone. This is because React decides what your HTML should look like based on the data and what you put in your JSX. Resetting the form changes the HTML, but it doesn't update the states in React, so nothing is really changed.

Comment: That makes sense! It took awhile for me to understand but I learned alot from it. Thank you for walking through, I appreciate it! Not sure if I'm understanding it right but in ```toggle``` function of after looping every list item and index, are you listing all the items from the  ```list``` by using ```...listItem```? So basically the current list is in ```...listItem```.

Comment: Happy to help out. In the `toggle` function we're looping over every object in the `list` array. So `listItem` is a singular object. In React you want to avoid manipulating existing state values and instead create new values to update the state with. With `{ ...listItem }` we're copying the properties of `listItem` into a new object as we need most of the properties without any alteration. Except for the `checked` property which we need to override. The `...` is part of the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: That makes sense. I was going through spread operator docs and was wondering if that was copy. All the dots are connected now. Thank you!